# OData v4 Web API 2 dynamic properties do not persist

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have tried to implement the sample from 
[Open Types in OData v4 with ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4)

I am using the ODataConventionModelBuilder and included an entity with property:

```
public IDictionary<string,object> properties { get; set; }
```

I can post a new entity including dynamic properties; they show up in the Post Controller method, but they won't persist in the database. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: where is the code to establish connection between database and your Post method? are you following the tutorial as such?

Comment: This tutorial uses an in-memory dataset, but I just used the persistence method described on the same site using a local SQL database: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint